# force directed graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, d3-force-directed

i am trying to make a force directed graph using d3 and i am in latest version v7.

```
  const width = 800;
const height = 800;

var layoutCanvas = d3
  .select("#graphDiv")
  .append("canvas")
  .attr("width", width + "px")
  .attr("height", height + "px")
  .node();

// this.setState({ canvasAdded: true });
let context = layoutCanvas!.getContext("2d")!;

if (!context) {
  console.log("no 2d context found");
  return;
}

var transform = d3.zoomIdentity;

d3.json("test1.json").then((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
  const simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation(data.nodes)
    .force("charge", null)
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter())
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(data.edges));

  initGraph(data);

  function initGraph(data) {
    simulation.on("tick", simulationUpdate);

    function simulationUpdate() {
      context.save();
      context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      context.translate(transform.x, transform.y);
      context.scale(transform.k, transform.k);

      data.edges.forEach(function (d) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
        context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
        context.stroke();
      });

      // Draw the nodes
      data.nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(d.x, d.y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        context.fillStyle = d.col ? "red" : "black";
        context.fill();
      });

      context.restore();
    }
  }
});
```

this is my code and the test1.json file is this:[source](https://github.com/pravinpoudel/geneterrain-react/blob/master/test_small_spec.json)

When i log that data that is read from the d3.json() function

[image]
My major problem is that the canvas is 800x800 but when i log the node and edge position it shows above 800.

If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Ps: the position X and Y in json is in between 0 and 1.